# How can I create a typed IEnumerable in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, interface, iterator, ienumerable

I can do this:

```
public class EnumerableTest : System.Collections.IEnumerable
{
    System.Collections.IEnumerable data;

    public EnumerableTest(System.Collections.IEnumerable d)
    {
        data = d;
    }

    public System.Collections.IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (object s in data)
        {
            yield return s;
        }
    }
}
```

But I can't do this?:

```
public class EnumerableTestString : System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>
{
    System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string> data;

    public EnumerableTestString(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string> d)
    {
        data = d;
    }

    public System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (string s in data)
        {
            yield return s;
        }
    }
}
```

The error I get basically says I am missing the method

```
    public System.Collections.IEnumerator GetEnumerator();
```

When I change the return type of `GetEnumerator()` to that, then it tells me I am missing

```
    public System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator();
```

If I try to include both, it tells me I have a duplicate method name.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create *both* - e.g. an `Explicit` implementation that will call the `Implicit` implementation.

**Example:**

```
public class EnumerableTestString : System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>
{
    System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string> data;

    public EnumerableTestString(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string> d)
    {
        data = d;
    }

    public System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (string s in data)
        {
            yield return s;
        }
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

> How can I solve this?

You need to use [*explicit interface implementation*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173157.aspx) to implement at least one of the `GetEnumerator` methods, usually the non-generic one.

The code is simply with `using` directives :)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class EnumerableTestString : IEnumerable<string>
{
    private IEnumerable<string> data;

    public EnumerableTestString(IEnumerable<string> d)
    {
        data = d;
    }

    public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (string s in data)
        {
            yield return s;
        }
    }

    // Explicit interface implementation for non-generic IEnumerable
    public IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        // Delegate to the generic version
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Implement `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>` instead.

When you do so using VS's smart tag, VS automatically creates two methods. One for the generic implementation and one for the non-generic one (the one you have already) because `IEnumerable<T>` requires you to implement `IEnumerable` as well.

```
public class StringData : IEnumerable<string>
{
    ...

    #region IEnumerable<string> Members

    public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (string s in data) {
            yield return s;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region IEnumerable Members

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();  // Calls generic GetEnumerator
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Note that the non generic method is implemented explicitly and can therefore only be accessed through the interface (`IEnumerable x = ...;    x.GetEnumerator()`). Its purpose is to increase the compatibility and is a remnant of pre-generic c# versions (1.0, 1.1).